# My Web App Services break when it gets built using Angular-CLI 1.6.2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Long time reader, first time question-poster.

I have build a simple web app (source code located [here](https://github.com/guillermoarellano/ga-ngx-masterdetail-demo)) that is built using Angular Material's Side Navigation module. I am using services that talk to the GitHub API to pull up all of the repos for a particular username, in this case the user is [heremaps](https://api.github.com/users/heremaps/repos), and displaying the repos in the side navigation. Then, the end-user clicks on a repo name and there's a service that shows the languages used for developing that particular repo in the main container. Here's an [example](https://api.github.com/repos/heremaps/bike-navigation/languages) of the response for the 'bike-navigation' repo.

The problem that I am having is that when I am working on my app in DEV mode, the services are working just fine. But when I build the app with using the command `ng build --prod` or if I serve my app using `ng serve --prod`, the service for pulling up the languages doesn't return anything. The browser console doesn't show any errors. And I have no idea how to troubleshoot the problem.

I am not using any routing in my app because it is a single page app with nested components that talk to each other.

My app has the main app template defined like this:

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
  <app-sidenav>loading</app-sidenav>
</div>
```

The SidenavComponent template then scaffolds the side navigation pane and its main content section. In the side navigation pane I instantiate the ReposListComponent, to ask GitHub for the list of repos. And then in the navigation main content section I pull in the RepoLanguagesComponent to listen and update itself everytime a new repo is selected.

**SidenavComponent** template:

```
<div class="container" [class.is-mobile]="mobileQuery.matches">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <h1 class="app-name">Master-Detail Demo app</h1>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" 
                        [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav [(opened)]="opened" 
                [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
                [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" 
                fixedTopGap="56">
      <app-repos-list (selectedRepo)="handleSelectedRepo($event)"></app-repos-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <h2 class="helper-text" *ngIf="!selectedRepoName">Click on top-left Menu to select a Repo.</h2>
      <app-repo-languages [repoName]="selectedRepoName" *ngIf="selectedRepoName"></app-repo-languages>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

**ReposListComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { ReposService } from '../shared/repos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-repos-list',
  templateUrl: './repos-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./repos-list.component.scss']
})
export class ReposListComponent implements OnInit {
  repos: any[];
  @Output() selectedRepo: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  errorMessage = '';

  constructor(private _reposService: ReposService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReposFromService();
  }

  onSelectedRepo(repo: any) {
    this.selectedRepo.emit(repo.name);
  }

  private getReposFromService() {
    this._reposService.getRepos().subscribe(
      data => this.repos = data,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

**RepoLanguagesComponent**:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { ReposService } from '../shared/repos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-repo-languages',
  templateUrl: './repo-languages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./repo-languages.component.scss']
})
export class RepoLanguagesComponent implements OnChanges {
  codingLanguages: any[];
  errorMessage = '';
  @Input() repoName: string;

  constructor(private _reposService: ReposService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['repoName'] && (this.repoName !== null && this.repoName !== undefined)) {
      this.getCodeLanguagesFromService();
    }
  }

  getCodeLanguagesFromService() {
    this._reposService.getRepoLanguages(this.repoName).subscribe(
      data => this.codingLanguages = data,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

The lone service in all of this, **ReposService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ReposService {
  private _heremapsGithubReposUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/heremaps/repos';
  private _heremapsGithubRepoLangUrl = 'https://api.github.com/repos/heremaps'; // append /:repo_name/languages to Url

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getRepos() {
    return this._http.get(this._heremapsGithubReposUrl)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getRepoLanguages(repoName: string) {
    const repoLanguagesAPIUrl = `${this._heremapsGithubRepoLangUrl}/${repoName}/languages`;

    console.log(repoLanguagesAPIUrl);
    return this._http.get(repoLanguagesAPIUrl)
      .map((response) => Object.keys(response))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMsg = '';

    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        errorMsg = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        errorMsg = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
  }

}
```

You can see my failing application running here --> https://ngx-masterdetail-demo.azurewebsites.net/

Source Code --> https://github.com/guillermoarellano/ga-ngx-masterdetail-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bug in angular-cli or on angular/cli.
I have updatet angular-cli with

```
npm update -g @angular/cli
```

Then I have changed the package.json of your project. I changed the line `@angular/cli": "1.6.2",` to `@angular/cli": "1.6.2",`

Then I called

```
npm update
```

Now it works just fine.

Comment: That was it! I updated my Angular CLI to version 1.6.7 and now everything works. Thank you @sweting for your help! Best regards, Guillermo